# Typescript compiler API: print PropertySignature on a single line

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to generate a function that returns an object-literal type (not sure if that's the correct term). I currently use the following:

```js
ts.createFunctionDeclaration(
    undefined, //decorators
    [], //modifiers
    undefined, //asterisk
    'foo',
    undefined, //name
    [], //parameters

    ts.createTypeLiteralNode( //return type
        [
            ts.createPropertySignature(
                undefined, //modifiers
                ts.createIdentifier('bar'),
                undefined, //question token
                ts.createTypeReferenceNode(
                    'string',
                    undefined //generics
                ),
                undefined //initializer
            ),
            ts.createPropertySignature(
                undefined, //modifiers
                ts.createIdentifier('baz'),
                undefined, //question token
                ts.createTypeReferenceNode(
                    'string',
                    undefined //generics
                ),
                undefined //initializer
            )
        ]
    ),

    ts.createBlock([
        //some interesting statements
    ])
);
```

This generates this code:

```js
function foo(): {
    bar: string;
    baz: string;
} {
    //interesting statements
}
```

It works, but I'd like the return type literal to be on a single line like this:

```js
function foo(): { bar: string, baz: string } {
    //interesting statements
}
```

Is this possible using *just the Typescript compiler API*, or do I need to use an external linter/formatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the emit flag `EmitFlags.SingleLine` on the type literal node:

```
const typeLiteralNode = ts.createTypeLiteralNode(...);
ts.setEmitFlags(typeLiteralNode, EmitFlags.SingleLine);
```

[`emitTypeLiteral`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/03aee9278274ac3ae43d402dc4809d7daf094c6b/src/compiler/emitter.ts#L1931) in [emitter.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/03aee9278274ac3ae43d402dc4809d7daf094c6b/src/compiler/emitter.ts) seems to indicate it's possible to do this.